# Django | <title> object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I get an error using with using form.save(commit=False) and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My view looks something like this:

**views.py**

```
def make_electable(request, election_id):
    election = get_object_or_404(CommissionElection, id=election_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MakeElectable(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            electable = form.save(commit=False)
            electable.election.set(election)
            form.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class MakeElectable(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
          model = ElectablePerson
          fields = ['commission',]
    commission = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Commissie.objects.all(), widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

**models.py**

```
class CommissionElection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    commission = models.ManyToManyField(Commissie)
    electable_time = DateRangeField()
    voting_time = DateRangeField()


class ElectablePerson(models.Model):
    commission = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    election = models.ManyToManyField(CommissionElection)
```

The error I get is:

> "<ElectablePerson: ElectablePerson object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

I don't see why the object is None. I suspect it has something to do with the manytomanyfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A many to many field is a table which uses 'id_electable, id_election' as keys, with commit=false, you don't persist which gives you no id. Following code should fix your issue.

```
if form.is_valid():
    electable = form.save()
    electable.election.add(election)
```

Also see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add for many to many relations.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add or set a many-to-many field if one of the two objects you link has not been created in the database first, since the objects need a token to get linked to each other, so:

```
def make_electable(request, election_id):
    election = get_object_or_404(CommissionElection, id=election_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MakeElectable(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            electable = form.save()
            electable.election.set(election)
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: Usually it is better not to work with `commit=False` when saving the form with the [**`.save(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method): this will revent saving many-to-many relations since these can only be saved if the item is committed. Usually it is better to alter the `.instance` wrapped in the form. For more information, see [my article<sup>[Django-antippaterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/using-commit-false-when-altering-the-instance-in-a-modelform.html) on this.

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.